# Confusion with enums and public classes - why it does not work?

Tags: c#, class, enums, accessibility

Having the following code, it keeps reporting inconsisteng accessibility but I do not understand why. It depends on the Program class being or not being public:

```
enum Test
    {A,B}

    public class Program  //when I remove public, it works
    {
        public Test a = Test.A;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have not explicitly declared an access modifier (ie. `public`, `protected`, `internal`) on your enum, it takes the default value (which is `internal` for classes and enums). You are then exposing that enum via a `public` field of your `Program` class, which is not allowed as the enum is not visible outside of its assembly.

You need to either declare the enum as `public`, or change the access modifier of the field to `internal` or `private`.

It works when you remove `public` from the `Program` class because it changes the `Program` class to be internal - the same as the enum. This is fine as neither of them are publicly exposed.

Comment: Yep, but I do not understand why the access modifier of program class matters.

Comment: Oh I got it I think. Its because different assembly could access the public Program class and its exposing the enum in the public field, but the enum itself is private (internal also)., right?

Comment: @Mojmi: Yes, that is correct. The accessibility of fields of a class are overridden by the accessibility of the class. eg. If a class is `internal` and it has a `public` field, the field cannot be accessed publicly because the class restricts access to it.

Comment: Thanks. One more thing, why the other responders use term property? I thought I learned the terminology and this is field, correct?

Answer (score 4):

You haven't put an access modifier on your enum declaration, and then you are exposing it as a `public` field of your `Program` class.  If you don't declare an access modifier, it is `private`.

```
public enum Test { A, B }
```

Comment: Thanks..btw property? I think its field of Program class. But why it works when the class is private?

Comment: Good point, its a field. When the class is `private`, it has the same accessibility level as the enum, so the `public` field is still restricted by the access modifier of the class it is contained in.

Comment: It's not `private`, it's `internal`. Unless they're members of another type.

Answer (score 2):

You can't make the property public because the enum is private. The public property would be externally public should someone use your program and the compiler tells you about it.

Comment: I do not understand. If the class is private, it works. Once I add "public" to class declaration, it does not work. and also, why you are calling it property? Is not it field?

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, it's of course a field. Though a field/property can only be public (expose) public enums, structs and classes so you need to declare your enum as public.

Answer (score 1):

you probably need to set the enumeration to public